# how to print counted sql query using php

Tags: php

I try to count the event-code. What are the changes I need to do to achieve it?
Please help me with that.

My code:

```
$serverName = "IE3PDT1QJ67P4"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"TestEventsDB");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}
else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$sql = "SELECT count(EventCode)  FROM AlarmPointEvent where AlarmPoint=24001";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  echo $row['EventCode']."<br>";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

?>
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: you should give the column a name with `count(EventCode) AS EventCodeCount` and then you can use `$row['EventCodeCount']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will set a alies name for count,

```
$serverName = "IE3PDT1QJ67P4"; 
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"TestEventsDB");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

if( $conn ) {
 echo "Connection established.<br />";
}
else{
 echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
 die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$sql = "SELECT count(EventCode) as eventcount  FROM AlarmPointEvent where AlarmPoint=24001";
 $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
 }

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
 echo $row['eventcount']."<br>";
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt( $stmt);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do some change here

```
   $sql = "SELECT count(EventCode) as total_event FROM AlarmPointEvent where AlarmPoint=24001";
```

and here

```
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
  echo $row['total_event']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: I glad that I am of your help